# Trying to find a Element within a context on jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My objective is to find a element within a context, in this case, a set of jQuery HTML elements.
I'm seems easy, but why does it fail??

```
s= "<h3 id='boi'> Oi putinho </h3> <p sub='a#b'> Oi oaosidoias aosd asoid aosidoi asodi sa </p>"

j(':first') // => [html]
j(s) // => [h3#boi, <TextNode textContent=" ">, p]
j(':first', j(s)) // => [] ?! Fail
```

ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#expressioncontext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.filter`.

```
$(s).filter(':first')
```

Or simply

```
s.filter(':first')
```

Comment: I keep confusing this function in favor of .find(), Tnxs

Answer (score 3):

If you want the first one, you can get it by its index using [jQuery's `.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
j(s).eq( 0 ); // Get wrapped element at index 0 (first item)
```

Or if you just want the DOM element unwrapped, use [jQuery's `.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

```
j(s).get( 0 ); // Get DOM element at index 0 (first item)
```

...or using square bracket notation.

```
j(s)[ 0 ]; // Get DOM element at index 0 (first item)
```

You can also get a range of them [using `.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

```
j(s).slice( 0, 2 );  // Get the first two elements, wrapped in jQuery
```

If you wanted it using a selector, [see @meder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170333/trying-to-find-a-element-within-a-context-on-jquery/4170345#4170345).

Comment: +1 Very complete and would work for my example! But in my case the selector I wanted were more complex, I choose :first for being simple :P

Comment: `:first` is probably a little bit slower - I'd personally go with this answer